# Android GCM Unable to start service Intent

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

Hello I want to make a simple notification application. 
I am using this (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rmzv716SYkQ) tutorial. 
here is my codes.

**manifest file**

```
<uses-sdk
      android:minSdkVersion="8"
      android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<permission
    android:name="com.myapp.ntfapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.turk.bakistik.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
```

**manifest file in application block**

```
<receiver 
        android:name=".MyNotificationService"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
        <category android:name="com.myapp.ntfapp" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

**MyNotificationService Class**

```
public class MyNotificationService extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (action.equals("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION")) {
                String registrationId = intent.getStringExtra("registration_id");
                Log.i("ui", registrationId);
                String error = intent.getStringExtra("error");
                String unregistered = intent.getStringExtra("unregistered"); 
            }
            else if (action.equals("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE")) {
                String data1 = intent.getStringExtra("data1");
                String data2 = intent.getStringExtra("data2");
            }
        } finally { }
    }
}
```

**Activate and Deactivate buttons in main activity**

```
button2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2); 
button3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3); 

button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
    public void onClick(View v) {   
        Intent registrationIntent = new Intent("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER");
        registrationIntent.putExtra("app", PendingIntent.getBroadcast(v.getContext(), 0, new Intent(), 0));
        registrationIntent.putExtra("sender", "123456789101112");
        startService(registrationIntent);   
    }
});

button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
    public void onClick(View v) {   
        Intent unregIntent = new Intent("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.UNREGISTER");
        unregIntent.putExtra("app", PendingIntent.getBroadcast(v.getContext(), 0, new Intent(), 0));
        startService(unregIntent);  
    }
});
```

When I click activate button

```
W/ActivityManager(70): Unable to start service Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION (has extras) }: not found
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I see an inconsistency in your manifest :

```
<permission
android:name="com.myapp.ntfapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.turk.bakistik.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

You should use your app's package name in both (either `com.myapp.ntfapp`
or `com.turk.bakistik`).

In addition, you are using an old and obsolete way to register to GCM. You should use the GoogleCloudMessaging.register method which is part of the Google Play Services library.

Comment: thanks Eran. but tried your suggestion and corrected inconsistency  before asking this question.